# error on listing all files using google drive api in php

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am working on google drive api by using PHP. I am facing an error while using this drive api. I am using google api client library "google/apiclient ^2.0". I am trying to user login with google authentication and view all files available in drive for this purpose, i am using this library but it's showing error:

> Notice: Undefined property: Google_Client::$files in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/google_app/index.php on line 31
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function listFiles() on
>   null in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/google_app/index.php:31
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/google_app/index.php(55):
>   retrieveAllFiles(Object(Google_Client)) #1 {main} thrown in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/google_app/index.php on line 31

```
include_once   'vendor/autoload.php';


function retrieveAllFiles($service) {
  $result = array();
  $pageToken = NULL;

  do {
    try {
      $parameters = array();
      if ($pageToken) {
        $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
      }
      $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

      $result = array_merge($result, $files->getItems());
      $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
      $pageToken = NULL;
    }
  } while ($pageToken);
  return $result;
}


$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secrets.json');
$client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access
//$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
}
$service = new Google_service_Device();
echo retrieveAllFiles($service );
```

Actually i am trying to retrieve all files in my google drive with my file id and after that set status auto publish of specific files. Please help me to get rid of this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error explains itself very clearly. Have you tried reading the error?

Comment: Now it's giving new error "Daily limit for unauthenticated Use Exceeded" ? Why does this happen? i only try my code 4 or 5 times. How can i get rid of this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Daily limit for unauthenticated Use Exceeded"

Means that you are making a request without properly authenticating your script. there is probably something up with your fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode.

You might consider something long these lines

```
function getOauth2Client() {
    try {

        $client = buildClient();

        // Set the refresh token on the client. 
        if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
            $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
        }

        // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
        // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {

            // Set the access token on the client.
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);                 

            // Refresh the access token if it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
            }           
            return $client; 
        } else {
            // We do not have access request access.
            header('Location: ' . filter_var( $client->getRedirectUri(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Code ripped from my sample project [oauth2php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.php)

> Undefined property  Google_Client

Means you havent properly declared the google client

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function listFiles() on null in

what happens if you remove $parameters and just call $service->files->listFiles();

Comment: great gotcha !! thanks @DalmTo. One more thing can you tell me how i will define multiple scopes in addscope function

Comment: $client->addScope("scope3");  will append scope3 onto your scopes.    $client->addScope(array("scope4", "scope5"));  will  add more then one.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! @DalmTo

Comment: Got an error after some work that it says refresh token must be passed or set as part of setAccessToken.

Comment: you might want to check out the other half of that sample file https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v3/oauth2callback.php

Comment: Thanks for your help